# get an error while applying a widget to a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here is my model

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    serving_size = models.ForeignKey(ServingSize)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

and my model form

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipe_ingredient = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient

        widgets = {
            'serving_size' : forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'test'}), 
            'recipe_ingredient' : forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

I get the following error when I navigate to the page

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0x1010faf50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 245, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/models.py", line 128, in <module>
    RecipeIngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, RecipeIngredient, extra=1, form=RecipeIngredientForm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 838, in inlineformset_factory
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 669, in modelformset_factory
    formfield_callback=formfield_callback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 407, in modelform_factory
    return ModelFormMetaclass(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 220, in __new__
    opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 178, in fields_for_model
    formfield = formfield_callback(f, **kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
```

but if I remove this line from my RecipeIngredientForm the error goes away

```
'serving_size' : forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'test'}),
```

Any ideas whatI did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't add Select widget to this field, it's `ModelChoiceField`, and is rendered as `select` box anyway. If you put `Select` widget on ModelChoiceField, it won't render properly (will show **unicode** output in `value` rather than ID).

Also you don't need the first CharField unless you want a text input with auto-completion.

To show the input element with custom attributes, use {% field %} tag:

```
{% field myform.myselect class="XYZ" %}
```

renders it to

```
<select name="..." class="XYZ">...
```

I think you'll agree that it's a bad idea to customize classes and templates inside forms or models. It makes it impossible to debug templates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is actually a bug in djano (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13095). If you can clarify some of the things you mentioned. You said that don't add the select widget, but if I wanted to add a class attributes, how would I do it? The select field is rendering properly, the issue was with the custom field in the custom modelform class.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.

I specified a custom "form" kwarg in a modelformset_factory constructor.  This would consistently fail with the error you describe while that form class had custom widgets specified in its meta class:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    widgets = {
        'myField' : forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
    }

MyFormFactory = modelformset_factory(MyModel,form=MyForm)
```

Changing the form class to specify custom widgets in the **init** method seemed to solve this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.fields['myField'].widget = forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
```